# Gnupg library issues on Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, solaris-11

I have installed gnupg from the official Solaris 11 repository, but am experiencing library issues. This is the error I am getting:

```
ld.so.1: gpg2: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5: symbol tgetent: referenced symbol not found
```

See more information here:

```
bash-4.1$ gpg2 --list-secret-keys
Warning: using insecure memory!
/www/shared/.gnupg/secring.gpg
------------------------------
sec 1024D/E6A51C54 2010-11-25
uid John Doe (jdoe) <john@doe.com>
ssb 2048g/2BE06126 2010-11-25

bash-4.1$ gpg2 --edit-key john@doe.com
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.17; Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Warning: using insecure memory!
Secret key is available.

pub 1024D/E6A51C54 created: 2010-11-25 expires: never usage: SC
trust: unknown validity: unknown
sub 2048g/2BE06126 created: 2010-11-25 expires: never usage: E
[ unknown] (1). John Doe (jdoe) <john@doe.com>

ld.so.1: gpg2: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5: symbol tgetent: referenced symbol not found
Killed
bash-4.1$ pkg list |grep readl
library/readline 5.2-0.175.0.0.0.2.537 i--
bash-4.1$ pkg list |grep gnup
crypto/gnupg 2.0.17-0.175.0.0.0.2.537 i--
bash-4.1$ ls -al /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin 412864 Jun 20 2012 /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5
bash-4.1$ which gpg2
/usr/bin/gpg2
bash-4.1$ ldd /usr/bin/gpg2
libc.so.1 => /lib/libc.so.1
libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1
libbz2.so.1 => /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2
libreadline.so.5 => /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5
libgcrypt.so.11 => /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.11
libgpg-error.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0
libassuan.so.0 => /usr/lib/libassuan.so.0
libsocket.so.1 => /lib/libsocket.so.1
libnsl.so.1
```

Please let me know if I have to provide more information!

Comment: `tgetent()` is a curses call.  Perhaps `libreadline` is linked against `ncurses`.  Try installing it.

Comment: ncurses is already installed.

Comment: Is it in the library paths returned by `crle`?

Comment: Yes. Default Library Path (ELF):   /lib:/usr/lib  (system default)

Comment: Does `ldd /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5` give anything useful?

Comment: ldd /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5

        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1

        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in gpg2 in Solaris 11.0 (aka Solaris 11 11/11), originally filed as Sun bug 7098984, now known as [bug 15747076 in the Oracle bug tracking system](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/ui/km/BugDisplay.jspx?id=15747076&bugProductSource=Oracle&recommended=true) [Oracle support account required to view].

It’s fixed in Solaris 11.1 and later releases.   For Solaris 11.0, this workaround helps in some cases (but not if you're using pfexec/sudo/etc.):

```
env LD_PRELOAD_32=/usr/lib/libcurses.so.1 gpg2
```

Comment: This is the working solution.